# Rewriting product URL with keyword product in woocommerce for third party API

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, woocommerce, permalinks

We have woocommerce installed.
We are trying to integrate a third party API. The server sends a request to Woocommerce to get a particular info.

When the URL is:

http://demo.geelani.net/s2pw/test/test1/?id=guid&call=GetPrices&product=2100022;2100023;2100022e&quantity=2&additionalSheetCount=4

It says not found.

However, when we change the parameter "product" in above URL to Product or product1, it works fine. Ex: http://demo.geelani.net/s2pw/test/test1/?id=guid&call=GetPrices&Product=2100022;2100023;2100022e&quantity=2&additionalSheetCount=4

We feel the issue is how the products are fetched by woocommerce and is conflicting with it. It has to do with permalinks or wordpress.

One possible solution is rewriting the URL using htacces. but how do we do this?

The current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /s2pw/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /s2pw/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I changed it to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /s2pw/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /s2pw/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /test/test1/\?id=(.*)&call=(.*)&product=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /test/test1/?id=%2&call=%3&Product=%4? [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /test/test1/\?id=(.*)&call=(.*)&product=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /test/test1/?id=%2&call=%3&Product=%4? [R=301,L,NE]
```

It should change `http://demo.geelani.net/s2pw/test/test1/?id=guid&call=GetPrices&product=2100022;2100023;2100022e&quantity=2&additionalSheetCount=4` to `http://demo.geelani.net/s2pw/test/test1/?id=guid&call=GetPrices&Product=2100022;2100023;2100022e&quantity=2&additionalSheetCount=4`

I would look into why the api is calling `product` instead of `Product` or see if you can get the script in the `test1` folder to allow calls to `product`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please refer the code above. The one you provided, still gives the 404 not found error. Thanks again.

Comment: Try moving the rewrite cond and rule to above the first rewrite rule